# FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE, probably caused by: ntkrnlmp.exe

Tags: bsod, crash, windows-10-v1703, segmentation-fault, windbg

My laptop suddenly crashed with the following screen.

[image: Windows 10, crash, BSOD, FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE, Your PC ran into a problem and needs to restart. We're just collecting some error info, and then we'll restart for you, stopcode]

After reboot I've opened `memory.dmp` under [WinDbg](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86) with the following details:

```
Loading Dump File [D:\Debug\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 15063 MP (16 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`1568f000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`159e0700
Debug session time: Mon Aug 13 16:53:42.380 2018 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 4:40:43.056
Loading Kernel Symbols...
Loading User Symbols
PEB address is NULL !
Loading unloaded module list
*******************************************************************************
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*******************************************************************************
BugCheck 12B, {ffffffffc00002c4, 58b, 4376a8d0, ffff9380d2bd6000}
Probably caused by : ntkrnlmp.exe ( nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmPageError+117 )
Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff800`1580d100 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:ffff9380`d5154550=000000000000012b
5: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*******************************************************************************

FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE (12b)
This bugcheck indicates that a single bit error was found in this page.  This is a hardware memory error.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffffffc00002c4, virtual address mapping the corrupted page
Arg2: 000000000000058b, physical page number
Arg3: 000000004376a8d0, zero
Arg4: ffff9380d2bd6000, zero

Debugging Details:
------------------

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834
SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  GL702ZC
SYSTEM_VERSION:  1.0       
BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.
BIOS_VERSION:  GL702ZC.305
BIOS_DATE:  05/10/2018
BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  GL702ZC
BASEBOARD_VERSION:  1.0       
DUMP_TYPE:  1
BUGCHECK_P1: ffffffffc00002c4
BUGCHECK_P2: 58b
BUGCHECK_P3: 4376a8d0
BUGCHECK_P4: ffff9380d2bd6000
SM_COMPRESSION_FORMAT: 3
SM_SOURCE_PFN1: 1a1968
SM_SOURCE_PFN2: ffffffffffffffff
SM_SOURCE_OFFSET: 1a8d0
SM_SOURCE_SIZE: 58b
SM_TARGET_PFN: 20859d
SM_BUFFER_HASH: e4696748
SM_ONEBIT_SOLUTION_COUNT: 1
BUGCHECK_STR:  0x12B_c00002c4_StCtDecompressFailed_ONEBIT
CPU_COUNT: 10
CPU_MHZ: bb2
CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD
CPU_FAMILY: 17
CPU_MODEL: 1
CPU_STEPPING: 1
BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)
DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT
PROCESS_NAME:  MemCompression
CURRENT_IRQL:  0
ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  KENORB-ROG
ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  08-13-2018 17:25:09.0439
ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18206.1001 amd64fre
LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff800158dcd77 to fffff8001580d100

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff9380`d5154548 fffff800`158dcd77 : 00000000`0000012b ffffffff`c00002c4 00000000`0000058b 00000000`4376a8d0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff9380`d5154550 fffff800`1583bc0b : 00000000`00000200 00000000`00000003 00000000`4376a8d0 ffff9380`d2bd6000 : nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmPageError+0x117
ffff9380`d51545a0 fffff800`1570ad2b : 00000000`00000000 ffff9380`d51547b8 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000102e : nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmSinglePageCopy+0x130eab
ffff9380`d5154680 fffff800`1570a74b : 00000000`00000001 00000000`0001a8d0 00000000`0001a8d0 00000000`00010000 : nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmSinglePageTransfer+0x7b
ffff9380`d51546d0 fffff800`1570a56e : ffff9380`ffffffff ffffde01`f9604000 ffff9380`d51547b8 ffffde01`fe1a2770 : nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmpSinglePageRetrieve+0x183
ffff9380`d5154770 fffff800`1570a04f : ffffde01`fe1a2770 fffff800`00000000 ffffffff`00000001 ffffde01`fe1a2770 : nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmPageRetrieve+0xea
ffff9380`d5154830 fffff800`157c7801 : ffffde01`e2fba000 ffff9380`d5154940 fffff800`157c77e0 ffff9380`d5154940 : nt!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStDirectReadIssue+0x6f
ffff9380`d5154880 fffff800`1575017b : ffffde01`eb4fe080 ffff9380`d5154940 00000000`00000002 fffff800`157b03e0 : nt!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStDirectReadCallout+0x21
ffff9380`d51548b0 fffff800`157b0335 : 00000000`00000003 ffffde01`f9604000 ffffde01`e2fba000 ffffde01`fe1a2770 : nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutInternal+0x8b
ffff9380`d5154900 fffff800`156ff2a2 : ffff9380`d5154a00 fffff800`15a89a00 00000000`00000000 fffff800`15709680 : nt!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStDirectRead+0xad
ffff9380`d51549d0 fffff800`156feb0a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff9380`d5154a80 ffffde01`fe1a2770 : nt!SMKM_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::SmStWorkItemQueue+0x1ae
ffff9380`d5154a20 fffff800`157093ba : 00000000`0000000c 00000000`00000010 ffffde01`fe1a2770 ffffde01`feab42f0 : nt!SMKM_STORE_MGR<SM_TRAITS>::SmIoCtxQueueWork+0xce
ffff9380`d5154aa0 fffff800`157b703a : ffffde01`00000010 ffffde01`feab43a0 ffffa980`00000000 ffffde01`e2fba000 : nt!SMKM_STORE_MGR<SM_TRAITS>::SmPageRead+0x16a
ffff9380`d5154b10 fffff800`156da1e9 : 00000000`00000000 ffff9380`d5154e40 ffffde01`ecab3580 00000000`00000000 : nt!SmPageRead+0x2e
ffff9380`d5154b60 fffff800`156d77fd : 00000000`00000002 ffff9380`d5154bf0 00000000`00000000 ffffde01`feab42a0 : nt!MiIssueHardFaultIo+0x11d
ffff9380`d5154bb0 fffff800`156c75fa : 00000000`c0033333 ffffde01`ecab3580 00000000`00000004 ffff9380`d5154e40 : nt!MiIssueHardFault+0x22d
ffff9380`d5154c50 fffff800`1581a4da : 00000000`019f020e ffffde01`d84c8a00 00000000`00000000 00007ff7`58fbe020 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x123a
ffff9380`d5154e40 00007ff7`58f541cf : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x31a
00000011`189a8970 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff7`58f541cf

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  0e25f7e1a5e1caae3d28e6a7023983c4503045c5
THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  6a53b912d1bc54590b0e960082de00d75d2c86f4
THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  82d14546c43bd06881f781d6d197c4c7f7ceb9cb
FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmPageError+117
fffff800`158dcd77 cc              int     3
FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  448b44cc
SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1
SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!ST_STORE<SM_TRAITS>::StDmPageError+117
FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
MODULE_NAME: nt
IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe
DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5b346c58
STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb
BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  117
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x12B_c00002c4_StCtDecompressFailed_ONEBIT_nt!ST_STORE_SM_TRAITS_::StDmPageError
BUCKET_ID:  0x12B_c00002c4_StCtDecompressFailed_ONEBIT_nt!ST_STORE_SM_TRAITS_::StDmPageError
PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x12B_c00002c4_StCtDecompressFailed_ONEBIT_nt!ST_STORE_SM_TRAITS_::StDmPageError
TARGET_TIME:  2018-08-13T15:53:42.000Z
OSBUILD:  15063
OSSERVICEPACK:  0
SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0
OS_REVISION: 0
SUITE_MASK:  272
PRODUCT_TYPE:  1
OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64
OSNAME:  Windows 10
OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS
OS_LOCALE:  
USER_LCID:  0
OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2018-06-28 06:04:24
BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  170317-1834
BUILDLAB_STR:  rs2_release
BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.15063.0.amd64fre.rs2_release.170317-1834
ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  eb9
ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM
FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x12b_c00002c4_stctdecompressfailed_onebit_nt!st_store_sm_traits_::stdmpageerror
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {8d8ee155-e853-3fdf-5c28-088ae99857a7}
```

Notes:

- The crash happened at random when closing *File Explorer*.
- I don't have any external devices apart of SSD card and *Bluetooth mouse*.
- Few days ago I got another BSOD, but different code (`DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE`).
- Most of the drivers are default one. No any reported problems in *Device Manager*.
- I've got system controlled paging files for all drives set as default.
- There is a 1x16GB DDR4 SODIMM, another slot is free (upgradeable).
- It's a brand new laptop purchased few weeks ago (without any upgrades).
- No any hardware modification or overclocking since the purchase.

Based on above information, is there any clear indication what happened? Is it a faulty driver, or memory?

Answer (score 3):

To me it looks like you have a faulty stick of memory:

> FAULTY_HARDWARE_CORRUPTED_PAGE (12b)
>   This bugcheck indicates that a single bit error was found in this page.  This is a hardware memory error.

Having a bad stick of RAM flipping a bit at bad times can cause all sorts of errors, from drivers expecting a 0 and getting a 1, to the contents of the page-file not being *quite* what was expected, to general corruption of critical system files such as the registry.

Run [memtest](https://www.memtest86.com/) and replace the faulty stick if it finds one.

If it does not find one then it might be a random bit flip that happened somewhere in the chain of loading it back in, which is a little unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion, is to clean each of your memory sticks with a hard pencil eraser. Then use an air duster to blow off any residual eraser material from the memory sticks and also remove dust from the memory slots on your motherboard.

I've had erroneous errors about memory and cleaning the memory sticks seemed to have helped. Of course each situation is different but it does not hurt to try.